# Is there a word or phrase that fits this scenario?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests

I had a conversation with a close friend about how much music they've listened to; the confusion started when she said 400, but she never specified what that number meant. I believed she said albums. When I asked her "400 albums?", she replied "I don't have that kinda time". But, I have listened to 400+ albums--she didn't know this until I told her after.

What would you call--if there is a word for this scenario where you are implicitly implicated into being the kind of person who has that kind of time where the person who said it did not have the intention of implicating you? I told her that this felt like a "sneak diss" to me.

But, sneak diss isn't the perfect way to describe this. Or is this all just a cultural stigma where time is meant to be spent earning money instead of dedicating them to hobbies?

**Too many of you are harping on the example:**

1. Yes, this was a misunderstanding on my part: we cleared it up.
2. She was talking about her time.
3. Her intention was not from a place of malevolence.

Comment: A put-down . . .

Comment: You may have misinterpreted what she said.  She may have been saying that she hadn't listened to 400 complete albums, but to 400 songs, or some such.

Comment: @HotLicks the misunderstanding was cleared up, but that still doesn't answer my question

Comment: This is usually the situation where "backhanded compliment" is used. "Wow! 400 albums? You must have so much time!" comes off as a compliment, but is sneakily an insult.

Comment: Based only on the information you provided, you drew an unsupported conclusion. Her saying that she doesn't have the time to listen to 400 albums doesn't mean that she even *knows* how many albums you've listened to, let alone that it's some kind of criticism. Did you leave out the fact that she knows how many albums you listen to? How do you know she wasn't just talking about herself and her own time?

Comment: After the edit, the question is still unclear. She simply said, "I don't have that kinda time." She said nothing about how other people might not or should not have that kind of time. If you made that leap in your own mind, and felt negative about it, then the word I would pick is **insecure**. Surely, many people listen to lots of music. Even people who aren't musicians. There's nothing negative about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me that she gave you an honest answer, and in doing so, she unintentionally or accidently or inadvertently offended you. In other words, she **stepped on your toes**. From M-W:

[**step on the toes of (someone)**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/step%20on%20the%20toes%20of%20(someone)) (idiom): to do something that upsets or offends (someone)

It's not absolutely necessary, but you could use, or not, an adverb such as *unintentionally* or *accidentally* or *inadvertently* to clarify your friend's lack of intent: she had no way of knowing that you've listened to 400+ albums, or that you would be so sensitive to her comment. In any event, she definitely **stepped on your toes**.

Comment: this fits perfectly, thank u

Comment: @S.Coughing You’re welcome. Thanks for your question. I enjoyed thinking about what you were seeking.

Answer (score 0):

First I thought "inculpate", which then lead me next to consider using "recriminate".

I'm not satisfied with either. The former because it's not clear, from how you described the interaction. If she was insinuating that you indeed had read 400 books, i.e., she thinks/knows that you have that time. It seems like you may have been doing all the work there by having a type of guilty mind. The latter maybe could work if you think she insinuated it, i.e., her response was an implied recrimination. If she didn't have that intention, perhaps we could say that she "unwittingly recriminated" you. But then aren't we creating an oxymoron there? Does recrimination require intentionality?

Comment: The guilty mindset does hit the nail on the head; I'm also not very satisfied with those two words.

Answer (score 0):

The best might be to *Insinuate* meaning to instill subtly or slyly, as into the mind some idea by suggestion. It does indeed work as a back-handed, or to be very old fashioned, *Left-handed* compliment.

Another term would be to *misapprehend*, which means to take the wrong meaning from what is said or intended. Whether you are worried about how they would or you would take this meaning is unclear. If you are concerned with avoiding being seen as elitist I have no idea how to proceed.

As far as  cultural stigma I think most would think a bit less of someone for keeping a count of their albums or books rather than if they took time to enjoy them.

Comment: The conversation was about consuming media in terms of how much? I don't think anyone would keep a count in their head--there's software that does it already: if they don't take the time to enjoy them, why would they dedicate so much time to them? It seems like a very odd flex; and, I felt that could've been my trajectory toward some form of elitism--a pit I tried to avoid, so I understand your conclusion. Insinuation doesn't seem to fit because the intention wasn't meant to be a snide comment. This scenario is like a guilty feeling where you've been found out and feel it to be an insult.

Answer (score 0):

> I told her that this felt like a "sneak diss" to me.

That's called *sniping*.

**Sniping (noun):**

2. *The action of verbally attacking someone in a sly or petty way.* ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sniping))

‘there has been some sniping about inept leadership’